# Use float with sourceRectangle monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

I try use the scale with monogame and for this I modify the sourceRectangle too for the hitbox but when I'm trying to assign 0.5 for scale the sourceRectangle.Width and Height = 0

because my calcul is

```
sourceRectangle.Width = (texture.Width / cols) * (int)this.scale.X
sourceRectangle.Height = (texture.Height / rows) * (int)this.scale.Y
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got your casting in the wrong place. The scale is getting rounded down to zero before it gets multiplied.

Try this instead:

```
sourceRectangle.Width = (int)((texture.Width / cols) * this.scale.X);
sourceRectangle.Height = (int)((texture.Height / rows) * this.scale.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what the type of your `sourceRectangle` is, but I guess its `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle` which uses `Int32` for its members.[Source](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Rectangle.cs)

If you want to have `0.5f` for the texture, you can scale the texture by 2 and then you don't have to get any "half" values. But other than that, there is no real options without modifying the `SpriteBatch`.

You can compile MonoGame for yourself and write yourself a floaty-`Rectangle` struct that can be given to the `SpriteBatch` and you can especially modify this method, because it uses float anyway: [Draw in SpriteBatch](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs#L253)